# Clarifications on Open edx using bitnami at microsoft azure

Tags: bitnami, openedx

i've successfully installed openEdx using bitnami in Microsoft Azure cloud.

i like to know below points, can anybody help me on this please!

1)I am a PHP programmer - but I reviewed few blogs , they mentioned the written script of edx is python etc, 
 is the edx script support PHP ? "

2) I can able to connect server through winscp. Can anyone tell me the exact root path?

3) Is Edx same as common Application Made using PHP & Mysql?

4) I seen, lot of modules are present & we need to install it to use ( Like we do plugins in Wordpress),
    then can we able to customize for our individual requirement?

5) kindly Suggest me good startup tutorial

Looking forward Your Replies, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I am a PHP programmer - but I reviewed few blogs , they mentioned the written script of edx is python etc, is the edx script support PHP ? "

The Bitnami Open edX Stack includes three three major components: `edX Platform`, `XQueue` and `edX Forum`. `edX Platform` and `XQueue` are written in Python and the `cs_comments_service` (forum) is written in Ruby. More info at:

- https://github.com/edx/edx-platform
- https://github.com/edx/xqueue
- https://github.com/edx/cs_comments_service

> 2) I can able to connect server through winscp. Can anyone tell me the exact root path?

Please take a look to the Bitnami Documentation regarding how to access via SSH/SFTP to a server:

- https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/faq/#how-to-connect-to-the-server-through-ssh
- https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/faq/#how-to-upload-files-to-the-server-with-sftp

> 3) Is Edx same as common Application Made using PHP & Mysql?

No. edX is much more complex since it uses Python, NodeJS, Ruby, RabbitMQ, MySQL, etc. You should take a look to the Open edX architecture:
http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-developer-guide/en/latest/architecture.html

> 4) I seen, lot of modules are present & we need to install it to use ( Like we do plugins in Wordpress), then can we able to customize for our individual requirement?

Yes, you can customise and add plugins/themes to edX.

- Plugins documentation:

  - https://open.edx.org/xblocks
  - https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/apps/edx/#how-to-enable-an-xblock-for-a-course
- Theming documentation:

  - https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/apps/edx/#how-to-enable-and-apply-a-custom-theme

> 5) kindly Suggest me good startup tutorial

You should take a look to the Bitnami Documentation for Open edX:
https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/apps/edx/

Comment: @Juan..Excellent reply.. Thank u so much. I'll take a look :)